# How can you change the DNS server used in VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, internal-dns, amazon-vpc

I made a mistake in my configuration and set up my VPC to 10.0.0.0/16 and that conflicts with some of the services run in docker which created an internal network which now has a few containers at 10.0.0.0/24.

I was wondering if I can simply change the DNS to point somewhere else or do some routing to enable it like

route 10.253.0.2/32 to 10.0.0.2/32 on the management console and change /etc/resolv.conf?  I tried to see if I can add the route, but won't give me the option of setting an IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use any routing tricks or change the DNS resolver's IP address in a VPC -- one of them is always the CIDR block base address +2 -- but perhaps you can use the other one, which is always 169.254.169.253 in every VPC.

> If [the `enableDnsSupport` attribute] is true, queries to the Amazon provided DNS server at the 169.254.169.253 IP address, or the reserved IP address at the base of the VPC IPv4 network range plus two will succeed.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html

It will be better in the long run to fix your configuration and use addresses in docker that are *completely* outside the VPC CIDR block.